# deploying react app to firebase takes me to firebase landing page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy my react app on firebase but i get this image shown all the time.

[image]

Steps I did

1. firebase init
2. Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys
3. What do you want to use as your public directory?  - public
   Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N) - No
4. ? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? (y/N) - No
5. File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) - No

Then I get `✔  Firebase initialization complete!

6. firebase deploy
   then I get `✔  Deploy complete!

when i check the URL mentioned I see the message as shown in the screen shot `Firebase Hosting Setup Complete`.

When I also tried changing the path for public to `"public": "public/firebase-auth-test",`in Firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public/firebase-auth-test",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Definitely I am doing something wrong but unable to figure out.

this is my project structure if that helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details about your react project build.

i did a [small extercise project](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-firebase) to deploy a vue js application and you need to proper build your frontend project and then call the firebase hosting deploy.

Check the package.json and other relevant files to fix your setup.